# Can't Get Port 8008 to work on AWS Apache Server

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, port

Title really says it. My Listen statements:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8081
Listen 8008
```

My VirtualHost tags:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory3"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8008>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory4"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have all of those ports enabled on my AWS instance.
Accessing each of the previous ports works perfectly, but 8008 does not. I'm not really sure why because it's listed as an HTTP alternate port just like 8080 and 8081. Anyone know what the problem is? Or know a different port I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure that the security group you've given the instance is allowing access to these ports.

For example; in the AWS Console and in the EC2 section. Select "Security Groups" under the Network & Security heading on the left side nav bar. Then locate your security group.

Select the "Inbound" tab and make sure you've allowed access to each port from the IP address range that suits your requirements. If you want it internet accessible the source should be: `0.0.0.0/0`.

You may be running in a VPC, in this case the setup is a little more complex as you need to make sure that instance can be reached externally. I'd suggest reading the AWS documentation for setting up a VPC with a single public subnet.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant when I said I had all the ports enabled on my AWS instance. Sorry I wasn't more descriptive with that.

Comment: are you running in a VPC or with classic EC2?

Comment: I'm running in a VPC, just started my account recently :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really seeing how that web page relates to my problem. I'm able to connect through ports 80, 8080 and 8081, just not 8008.